# Why My Apple iPhone 5s Rebooted automatically?

Tags: iphone, reboot

I was just using my iPhone 5s and it was in charging mode, but suddenly it re-boot without any specific reason, I am lil worried about it, I am still in warranty period and will you expect me to go to help center, or its just normal, Help center is really far from my home.

Comment: My phone is currently exhibiting the same behavior regularly (iPhone 5 that reboots whenever it is charging and locked). The crashlogs indicate that the watchdog timer is timing out. This is more the symptom, rather than the cause, I presume. I am able to work around the problem by charging my phone but *not* locking it.

Answer (score 1):

Without jailbreaking / being a developer with Xcode / etc, it's not easy to find what caused a reboot. If it only occurred once, I'm more inclined to say that there's nothing wrong, but regular reboots can indicate either a software or hardware fault. If the device reboots repeatedly, try restoring the device's OS in iTunes. If the problem persists then that may indicate hardware failure.